# H2 element issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the H2 element filled with "Portfolio" centered above the 2 img elements. I am having trouble doing this. Right now, it is stuck on the left side of the 2 .col-md-4 bootstrap columns. Could you point me in the right direction?

Here is [the codepen](http://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/JKmZzZ?editors=1100).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="portf row">
  <h2>Portfolio</h2>

  <div class="portfolio col-md-4">

    <img class="port1 img-responsive" src="https://s8.postimg.org/v4ol85ct1/hangman.jpg">
    <p>A game of hangman made with: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-responsive"><img src="https://s8.postimg.org/3kagp7ctx/BFSkinner.jpg" alt="pic 2">
    <p>A B.F. Skinner tribute page made with: HTML and CSS.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `display:flex` style on the `row` class is causing this. Adding the following CSS should fix the immediate issue:

```
.portf {
  display: block;
}
```

You might want to reconsider using `display:flex` on the `row` class. Much of your CSS could be simplified by removing it and centering the `col-md-8` columns by adding a `col-md-offset-2` class to them.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove row class first.
Then use col-md-6 class for both image div.
Hope this will help you.

```
 <div class="portf">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>

      <div class="portfolio col-md-6">
        <img class="port1 img-responsive" src="https://s8.postimg.org/v4ol85ct1/hangman.jpg">
        <p>A game of hangman made with: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 img-responsive">
        <img src="https://s8.postimg.org/3kagp7ctx/BFSkinner.jpg" alt="pic 2">
        <p>A B.F. Skinner tribute page made with: HTML and CSS.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please check link that you have included in your answer.